# Visual Basic 2010 - Create new folder for EVERY language (like right click: create new folder)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, directory

My question is: How do i create a folder with Visual Basic 2010 which names itself like you would create a new folder with rightclick inside an existing directory? (so if i click button1 on the form it creates a new directory without me having to specify the name and gives it the correct number afterwards (1), (2), ...)

Not System.Globalization.CultureInfo and an "if" which changes the language manually
(more like environment.createnewfolder(path without foldername)

Thx

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code:

```
MkDir("C:\Directory")
```

This will make a directory (folder) named "Directory" in the C:\ drive.